# No puedo compilar en Visual Studio code

Tags: c++, vscode, compilar

Instale VSC para programar en C++, tambien hice la instalacion del WinGW.

El problema es que VSC me marca un error al querer compilar.

[image: Este el el mensaje que muestra al darle F5]

Después de darle Debug Anyway, me da esto:

[image]

Ya no se que hacer para poder usar VSC

Comment: Por favor evita el uso de palabras soeces

Comment: Y si compilas manualmente en la terminal que te sale?